# React-native image with headers

Tags: react-native

How to pass headers into `Image` element?

This approach does not fit due to impossibility to cache images and base64 conversion will be hard with small RN Js-thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36678631/6119618

This is not working at all on neither android nor ios
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713741/6119618

I don't want yet eject my project, so modules like `FastImage` and others using `react-native link` will not work

**UPD**
tried to launch the same app on ios and images aren't showing up. Android works

Comment: The second answer in that post is recommended by [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images), I think you should check your code

Comment: @harlan I cannot make it work. I'm passing url and headers the same as into postman. Postman 200 OK, react native not showing image. Image size is big, no styles like opacity, position absolute and others

Comment: Did you try to capture the network packages and analyse the true cause? Are you sure the request send by react native is wrong?

Comment: @harlan How to see what request react sends?

Comment: I use Wireshark and Charles,
 But in RN, this post may help you.
 [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063958/2444365](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063958/2444365) this may help you.

Comment: @Harlan wireshark doesn't see http requests from rn app only `/onchange` and packager http requests. I didn't understand how to use charles

Comment: How are you determining that it's a header problem? Is the server getting those requests? Did you perhaps forget to set width/height to your images?

Comment: @nimrod no, i tried to replace uri with image that doesn't require headers, it showed up. width and height are set.

Comment: I think that without showing us the code you tried, it's going to be very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @nimrod i perform everything need to share code to you and chat you tomorrow

Comment: @nimrod@harlan sorry guys, it was bug of mine. Thanks all, everything works as it should

Comment: Might be a silly question but are using the true React Native Image component or some abstraction from it because the above works fine for me on the raw Image component but not on the NativeBase Image (for example).

Comment: @andy true image component

Answer (score 1):

The better approach would be something like this.

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

<Image 
  source={{ 
    uri: 'source uri',
    headers: {
      ...headers
    }
  }}
/>
```

Above method would work for almost every case, However you can also separately fetch the image using fetch api or axios (pass the headers in the request). Then store the base64 in state and then use that as uri.

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy

```
<FastImage or <Image
              style={{
                //your style
              }}
              source={{
                //your source
                uri: props.item.img,
                //your headers
                headers: {
                //authorization example
                  Authorization: 'Basic bmFzc2VyOmw2NTExZzhrXyZ1SA==',
                },
              }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

After long time i turn out that all the problems about this theme caused by issues in my code. Who did know that `borderRadius` 1000 rounds off that so strong, that element becomes fully rounded from within. Question is closed, thanks all